# Linkers, do they copy object code or simply reference it?

Tags: c++, c, binary, linker

I understand the relevance and job of a linker in C,  but what is happening in the binary? Does the linker copy the binary,  from say,  a DLL or does it simply reference this library function in binary to carry out the function?

Comment: They copy it into the executable — unless it's a shared library that is being referenced.

Comment: A DLL has an import table that describes what functions live in another module.  The linker creates that table.  The OS loader interprets it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of a DLL the linker  simply places references to the functions in the DLL in the executable code, which will (hopefully) be resolved at run-time. In the case of static linking the linker  copies the code from the library into the executable, and everything is resolved at link-time.

If you really want the full story about linkers, which few people seem really interested in, take a look at https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960 which is an excellent book.